# Constructors and Enums in Haxe

Tags: enums, haxe

I read over enums in Haxe and I found the constructor documentation rather confusing.  They say it supports constructors by they only give a very basic example:

`enum Color2 {
  Red;
  Green;
  Blue;
  Rgb( r : Int, g : Int, b : Int );
}`

Can I create a constructor function which parses a string to determine the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name "constructor" may be causing some confusion.  The terminology comes from treating "enums" as an object, and the "constructor" creates a new instance of that object.

In the color example:

```
// Variable `c` holds an object of type `Color`
var c:Color; 

// Set the value `c` to a `Color` object using the `Red` constructor.
c = Red; 

// Set the value `c` to a `Color` object using the `Rgb` constructor, 
// and values [255,255,0].
c = Rgb(255,255,0);
```

So each enum "value" is actually a constructor - the various values of "Color" are constructors for creating objects of type "Color".  It is confusing, because if a constructor has no arguments, you use it without the brackets: `Red`, which doesn't feel like a function call.

As for what you are asking about: can you create a function which parses a string to determine the value?

Not from an enum.  Enums can only have simple constructors as shown above.  You could have a helper class with a static method to help:

```
class ColorTools {
    static function make( name:String ) {
        return switch (name) {
            case "red": Red;
            case "blue": Blue;
            case "green": Green;
            case "black": Rgb(0,0,0);
            case "white": Rgb(255,255,255);
            default: throw 'unknown colour!';
        }
    }
}
```

But you cannot declare a helper method like this from inside an enum.

Comment: You actually can declare it with using.

Comment: @stroncium, you can have a "ColorTools" with static methods and then do `using ColorTools`, but you cannot add a static method (or any method) to the enum itself, it needs to live in a helper class.

Comment: Well, its a matter of abstraction. If you can define enum SomeEnum and then call method SomeEnum.ofString, I'd rather call it a method of enum. It is only an abstraction of when we attribute it to enum and when we do not.